# Div fade away on click and reveal other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So let's say I have something like this:

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 400px
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%
}

.td1,
.td2,
.td3 {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 2px #aaaaaa solid;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
  width: 100%;
}

.td2,
.td3 {
  border-top: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="td1">Here is some random text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="td2">This is the text you see at first</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="td3">This is the text below the other div</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Now, what I would like to do is have the td2 text to show when you first see the page, but not the td3. Then when clicking the td2 div it makes a fadeout or slides upwards, and then reveal the td3 div and that text. In this particular case the div doesn't have to come back when re-clicking. It's just like a "one way ticket". Click, and it's gone forever.

What might be the easiest way to do this ?

Comment: what you had done yet ? Please share your code

Comment: please show us something you have tried and not worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use JQuery UI to get the `fade` effect, and register to `click` event on `.td2` in order to update the DOM as per your requirement. Here's one way of doing it:

```js
$(".td2").on("click", function(){
 $(".td2").fadeOut();
  $(".td3").fadeIn();
});
```

```css
  body {
        background: #ffffff;
    }

    .table {
        display: table;
        margin: 0px auto;
        max-width: 400px
    }

    .row {
        display: table-row;
        width:100%
    }

    .td1, .td2, .td3 {
        display: table-cell;
        border: 2px #aaaaaa solid;
        padding: 15px;
        background: #eeeeee;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #000000;
        width:100%;
    }


    .td2, .td3 {
        border-top: none;
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="td1">Here is some random text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="td2">This is the text you see at first</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="td3" style="display:none">This is the text below the other div</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.td2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(200).promise()
    .done(function() {
      $('.td3').fadeIn(200);
    });
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0px auto;
  max-width: 400px
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="td1">
      Here is some random text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="td2">
      This is the text you see at first
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="td3 hide">
      This is the text below the other div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You will need to learn some javascript and some jQuery for this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.td3{
    display: none;
}
```

And write this javascript:

```
$('.td2').on( "click", function(){
   $('.td2').fadeOut();
   $('.td3').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: That will not work. You can't select `td2` as `#td2`.